# How call a method webdriver from another class in java?

Tags: java, selenium

i have a class Test1 where i use this line to click on a button:

```
 try{
      driver.findElement (By.xpath(Component._emp)).click();
      System.out.println("Employment is clicked");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e17) {
      System.out.println("Employment is not found [TEST FAILED]");  
}
```

And another class named Util, in this class i copied the code above like this:

```
public static void click_person_employment(){ 

    try{
         driver.findElement (By.xpath(Component._emp)).click();
         System.out.println("Employment is clicked");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e17) {
            System.out.println("Employment is not found [TEST FAILED]");    
        }
}
```

So in my class Test1 when i call like this:
Util.click_person_employment()

it throws java.lang.Nullpointer exception

Whta is the proper way to call this method.
My goal is to reduce code in my class Test1 because i have more than 100 buttons to click.
 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating more general methods in your Utils class, ones that you can reuse over and over.

Also, System.out.println is not recommended in code. Instead you can use a logging framework - SLF4J is a good one. If you insist on using System.out.println, you can pass on the message as well.

So I'd do something like:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger([className].class.getName());

public static void clickOnElement(By by){ 
try {
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(by).click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), e);   
    }
}
```

and then call it in test as:

```
Util.clickOnElement(By.xpath(...));
```

If you want the test to fail when the button is not found, you can rethrow the exception in the catch block.

PS. also, explicit waiting is always preferred to Thread.sleep - avoid that one in your tests as much as possible. :)

Comment: Hi, StopTheRain , i have a problem at this line WebElement element = driver.findElement(by).click(); ireplaced by by xpath and it says "The method by(String) is undefined for the type Util"

Comment: Can you post the value of the By that you send to clickOnElement(By by)?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, you can follow the below way:

First return `WebElement` from the **Util** class method -

```
public static WebElement click_person_employment(String empPath){
    WebElement elem = null;
    try{
         elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(empPath));
         //System.out.println("Employment is clicked");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e17) {
           System.out.println("Employment is not found [TEST FAILED]");    
    }

    return elem;
}
```

Then call this method from **Test1** class like

```
String empXpathStr = Component._emp;
WebElement element = Util.click_person_employment(empXpathStr);
element.click();
//Use WebDriverWait wait functionality here [Wait until element is visible]
```

You can also try removing the `static` keyword and creating the instance of **Util** class in your **Test1** class. Finally call the method from **Test1** class using the instance object.

Comment: @kirkdouglas I pushed an answer for your question and also vote up that question to come forward in the recent search.

Comment: Thank you but how do you delcare Component._emp as empPath?

Comment: @kirkdouglas This is nothing but a xpath string `for example:` `String empXpathStr  = "//*[@id='login-form']//*[contains(@class,'errorlist')]/li"`

Comment: I cannot figure out, it says Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement, i tried as you say String empPath = "//*....";

Comment: The error message is : java.lang.NullPointerException
 at utility.Util.click_site_new(Util.java:110)

Comment: @kirkdouglas I think, your accepted answer returns exception in the below line `WebElement element = driver.findElement(by).click();` Because click event can never be assigned to WebElement object.

Comment: @kirkdouglas you need to wait some time until element is visible otherwise it throws exception because you need to click more than 100 buttons. So the answer that you just accepted won't produce effective result as he didn't use WebDriverWait functionality. Beside this, he plagiarized some portion of my answer I think.

Comment: @kirkdouglas any other help regarding this let me know please.

Comment: thank you for your help, i will get back to you for sure. i didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: in this line WebElement element = driver.findElement(by(Component._mainMenu)).click(); in my Util.class file it says The method by(String) is undefined for the type Util